# Python Square Root doesn't work

Tags: python, loops, infinite

How come when I run this function it prints 3 and 4 alternating an infinite number of times. I can't understand why it keeps going, and also shouldn't it at least print 5 initially?

```
a = 15
x = 5
while True:
    print x
    y = (x + a/x) / 2
    if y == x:
        break
    x = y
```

Comment: Python 2 or python3?  On python2, you might want to enable true division and you'll probably want to have some sort of tolerance to the `y == x` since it could take a LONG time to get them to be actually equal.

Comment: I see a `print` statment.  It's python 2.  Also, it **does** print 5 initially.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing integer division. Change your constants to

```
a = 15.0
x = 5.0
```

Also, since the numbers will be `float` check for some allowable precision, instead of trying to use exact equality.

```
while True:
    print x
    y = (x + a/x)/2
    if abs(y - x) < 0.0001:
        break
    x = y
```

Output

```
5
4.0
3.875
3.87298387097
```

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you are using python 2, so `/` in this case integer division.  In order to force floating point division, there are a few ways you could do it, but this is probably the easiest.

```
y = (x + 1.0 * a / x) / 2
```

Comment: also, as pointed out by @mgilson, if floats were actually real numbers, this algorithm would never end. So instead of checking y==x, check abs(y-x) < 1e-8, for instance.

Comment: How could someone be named `recursive` and not have a link to http://stackoverflow.com/users/44743/recursive (or, better, the same with a query string…) in his About Me?

Comment: @abarnert: Sorry for the oversight.  I've corrected the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this small code trace will help you see the error:

First Loop

```
y= (5 +  (15/5)  ) /2
y= (5 + 3) /2
y=4

4 !=5

x=4
```

second loop

```
y= (4+(15/4))/2
y= (4+3)/2
y=3

3!=4
x=3
```

third loop

```
y=(3+(15/3))  /2
y=(3+5) /2
y=8/2
y=4

4!=3
x=4
```

will repeat...